# dynamic modfication of DateTime in the file content

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, datetime, powershell-2.0

I am trying to modify the date and time of our log records in a file with current time and save it in the same file, but somehow I am failing to update them.
The DateTime is dynamically changing, I wanted to change the DateTime for every record sequentially.

As you see below, the datetime is varying with seconds incrementally along with milliseconds - Is there a way that I can modify the files based on the current system time incrementally ? I have tried it the following way - I knew it is not correct but tried it to see if something works. Any suggestions or recommendations for this to fix, Please help.

Environment : Windows 2008 & Windows 2003

```
$PATH = "D:\Log\focusServer\focusServer.txt"
$content = "2015-10-27 15:50:21,900 [ListenerThread0] WARN  focus.Core.Server.States.InvalidIPRangeState - Begin 'InvalidIPRangeState' for application '|did:N/A^ep:10.160.210.222:40534^iprg:N/A|'
2015-10-27 15:50:21,900 [ListenerThread0] INFO  focus.Core.Server.Connection.DcmpConnection - |did:N/A^ep:01.60.210.222:40534^iprg:N/A|: Connection Established
2015-10-27 15:50:49,993 [12 ] INFO  focus.Core.Server.Connection.DcmpConnection - |did:N/A^ep:01.60.213.172:39158^iprg:N/A|: Connection Closed.  Reason: Socket closed by remote party (0-byte packet received)
2015-10-27 15:50:49,994 [ListenerThread0] WARN  focus.Core.Server.States.InvalidIPRangeState - Begin 'InvalidIPRangeState' for application '|did:N/A^ep:01.60.213.172:39158^iprg:N/A|'
2015-10-27 15:50:49,994 [ListenerThread0] INFO  focus.Core.Server.Connection.DcmpConnection - |did:N/A^ep:01.60.213.172:39158^iprg:N/A|: Connection Established"

$toReplace = "2015-10-27"
$updateContent = [DateTime]::Now.Add(0).AddHours(0).AddMinutes(0).addseconds(0).toString()
$convertDate = ([datetime]::ParseExact($updateContent,"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",$null))
$convertDate.year.toString() + "-" + $convertDate.month.toString() +"-"+ 
$convertDate.day.toString() + " " + $convertDate.Hour.toString() + ":" +$convertDate.Minute.toString() + ":" + $convertDate.Second.toString()

Add-Content -Value $content -Path $PATH

(Get-Content $PATH) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace $toReplace,$updateContent}  | 
Out-File $PATH
```

Comment: Can you show what you would want it to look like once complete? I can see multiple interpretations of what you requested. Are you just replacing the date and not the time?

Comment: Your parse exact formatting string does not match your sample data. Notice the dashes in data and slashes in your format string.

Comment: Initially, I tried to do this only with date but seems to be I need to change the time as well. I am trying to change the date and time for every record sequentially and save in the same file like : 
2015-10-27 15:50:21,900  [ListenerThread0] WARN  focus.....
2015-10-27 15:50:22,500  [ListenerThread0] INFO  focus.....
2015-10-27 15:50:22,900  [ListenerThread0] WARN  focus.....
2015-10-27 15:50:23,400  [ListenerThread0] INFO  focus.....

Comment: Show an example of the file _after_ the changes is what I am asking. You just repeated the source in comments. I know what to do with the time. I need to know what _exactly_ you are doing to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, You should be able to change what you need to based on this. What we do is edit every line in the file. Parse out the data from each line.... then manipulate said date and write it back to the same file.

In my example we are shifting the dates to today while keeping the same times of the original timestamps.

```
# file formatting. Note the space on the end is on purpose.
$formatting = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff "
$currentDate = Get-Date

(Get-Content $PATH) | Foreach-Object {
    # Split to get the date on the first occurrence of [.
    $parsed  = $_.split("[",2)
    # Convert to datetime
    $date = [datetime]::ParseExact($parsed[0], $formatting, $null)
    # Get the new time by adding the current date and the time from the parsed data
    $manipulated = $currentDate.Date + $date.TimeOfDay
    # Convert new time to the old format from file and append remainder of line from file.
    $manipulated.ToString($formatting) + "[" + $parsed[1]
} | Set-Content $PATH
```

Sample data output based on date of November 1, 2015 (today)

```
2015-11-01 15:50:21,900 [ListenerThread0] WARN  focus.Core.Server.States.InvalidIPRangeState - Begin 'InvalidIPRangeState' for application '|did:N/A^ep:10.160.210.222:40534^iprg:N/A|'
2015-11-01 15:50:21,900 [ListenerThread0] INFO  focus.Core.Server.Connection.DcmpConnection - |did:N/A^ep:01.60.210.222:40534^iprg:N/A|: Connection Established
2015-11-01 15:50:49,993 [12 ] INFO  focus.Core.Server.Connection.DcmpConnection - |did:N/A^ep:01.60.213.172:39158^iprg:N/A|: Connection Closed.  Reason: Socket closed by remote party (0-byte packet received)
2015-11-01 15:50:49,994 [ListenerThread0] WARN  focus.Core.Server.States.InvalidIPRangeState - Begin 'InvalidIPRangeState' for application '|did:N/A^ep:01.60.213.172:39158^iprg:N/A|'
2015-11-01 15:50:49,994 [ListenerThread0] INFO  focus.Core.Server.Connection.DcmpConnection - |did:N/A^ep:01.60.213.172:39158^iprg:N/A|: Connection Established
```

I saw that you were using regex. You *might* have had an issue there with control characters in your replacement string. My method is less error prone and opens up easier methods for date manipulation.

Comment: I apologize and Thank you very much. The sample data is exactly I am looking for but more of dynamic . The script works perfectly, but when I ran the script for the second time I got the exception.

I guess because the data is already there with the current date and when I delete the data and run it - I works perfectly. Is there a way, I can change the DateTime dynamically when I run the code every time.

Comment: I have figured it out - to add Clear the Content as the first step - so before each run - it clears the content and inserts the said content and modifies with the current date. Please let me know if it is a good method.

Comment: when tried the code again today, it only changes the date but not the time. Like hours, minutes, and seconds do not change - they stay the same and in our variable we are declaring those.

Comment: @user1911509 You said you wanted to increment time. So we used the current date and file time to make our new dates. If this is wrong you will need to change it. I had to _guess_ because I have asked you several time what the new time would _look_ like and you have not shown your expected output.